# Making Windows executables from Django applications

Tags: python, django, py2exe

I am trying to make a Django website be a simple Windows executable.  I've been told that `py2exe` does not work correctly, both due to Django using `__import__`, and to its attempting to dispatch `manage.py` in some obscure way.  Is that the case?  If so, is there an alternative tool that works better, or is there a way to work around the `py2exe` issues?

Comment: Sounds like all kinds of trouble to me, but I'm interested to see if there's a reasonable solution.

Comment: Just so that this doesn't sound *quite* so idiotic a question as it does on first reading: the use-case is a tiny little embedded server that won't ever actually be exposed to the world—hence why I'm not looking to integrate with IIS or the like.  The dev server (or something of similar calibre) is just fine for this use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/DjangoApplication).

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller trunk has been succesfully used to build Django applications. It has builtin support for many Django magic, but requires a careful setup (have a look at the [dedicated wiki page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Executable-From-Django)).